# how to group the closely related numbers from a set?

Tags: python

For Example consider the set:

```
   a = [123,234,345,456,124,568,10000,15000,564]
```

then i need to group the above numbers in the set as

```
   a = [123,234,345,456,124,568,564]
```

Example 2:

```
   a = [10000,12345,11000,10,5000,10500,13000]
```

then i need to group the above numbers in the set as

```
   a = [10000,12345,11000,10500,13000]
```

so the basic concept is to group the elements which are close to each other.so please suggest a general python code to do this?

Comment: 'close' --> where the difference b/w the numbers is comparatively less like 234-123=111 where as 10000-15000=5000 we can try it with any number.

Comment: your definition is not transitive. how would you group range(10000) then?

Comment: Can there be more than one group of "close" numbers in a set? E.g.: `[1, 2, 3, 1000, 1001, 1002]`?

Comment: I don't want to remove group range(10000) i just want to remove them from the list

Comment: @Blckknght yes there can be more than one group

Comment: @jhoncooper - Looks like you are trying to code some clustering algorithm in which case you are not being specific enough to define the clustering properties you want to have.

Comment: @Chandranshu-Can you suggest some clustering algorithm if it already exists plz

Comment: From the examples it seems like you may just be trying to remove outliers from a list, is that accurate? It doesn't seem like you're making multiple groups, you're just removing elements that are (fuzzily) dissimilar to most of the other elements.

Comment: I'll be surprised if the solution doesn't involve `itertools`. ;-)

Comment: @jhoncooper: What's the expected output for `[123,234,10000,11000,564,12000]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how many clusters you have, I suggest using `K-Means` clustering from the `scikit-learn` package:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2) # numbers will be clustered into 2 clusters based on euclidean distance
numbers = [123,234,345,456,124,568,10000,15000,564]
X = [[x] for x in numbers]
kmeans.fit(X)
zip(numbers, kmeans.predict(X))
```

Output (the first element is the number, the second is the cluster id assigned):

```
[(123, 1),
 (234, 1),
 (345, 1),
 (456, 1),
 (124, 1),
 (568, 1),
 (10000, 0),
 (15000, 0),
 (564, 1)]
```

Or for your second example:

```
[(10000, 0),
 (12345, 0),
 (11000, 0),
 (10, 1),
 (5000, 1),
 (10500, 0),
 (13000, 0)]
```

There are a number of other techniques like selecting the optimal number of clusters, but I'm afraid this is a bit out of scope. Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't believe he wants `124` in the cluster.  His distinction is the difference between them fits a pattern. `234` - `123` = `111` then `345` - `234` = `111`.  I suppose he could use these narrowed down groups to do the rest of testing for the group.

Comment: The specs are rather fuzzy, but I see what you mean. I think the OP needs to define a metric in this case.